# Multiple group by statements?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to group by location by day and need some help with the group by(or multiple group by statements?). The table looks like:

```
location    timestamp   traffic
1   US  2018-01-31  155
2   EU  2018-01-31  574
3   US  2018-01-30  149
4   EU  2018-01-30  150
5   US  2018-01-30  100
```

and I am trying to return:

```
location    timestamp   traffic
1   US  2018-01-31  155
2   EU  2018-01-31  574
3   EU  2018-01-30  150
5   US  2018-01-30  294  --(summed row)
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns:

```
SELECT   location, timestamp, SUM(traffic)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY location, timestamp
```